# Configuring PA Server Monitor for Windows monitoring

Tags: windows-server-2008, performance-monitoring, perfmon

My company got PA Server Monitor to monitor 6 servers. I have few questions regarding configuration.

So far I've made disk space and ping monitors. Generally two servers are IIS 7, two are SQL Server 2005 and the last remaining are streaming via FMS.

I want to get an alert when CPU usage is over 90%, memory is less than 15%. The problem is I don't know how these are called in perfmon.

If you have any advice for other monitors I would love to have them.

Comment: This is pretty application specific question, in my quick 90 second perusal of the documentation, it looks like you need to first have monitors, then event monitors, and then an action. It's all there in the manual.